# Using a dictionary to get total points for a scrabble word

Tags: python, dictionary, scrabble

I am having a really hard time answering this question for a class that I am taking. In this problem, I have to write a program using a dictionary containing letters with points. So any word that is entered, I have to output the number of points. The program that I am using is Python.

These are the instructions:

> Scrabble is a word game in which words are constructed from letter tiles, each letter tile containing a point value. The value of a word is the sum of each tile's points added to any points provided by the word's placement on the game board.*
>
> Write a program using the given dictionary of letters and point values that takes a word as input and outputs the base total value of the word (before being put onto a board).*

EX:

```
if the input is PYTHON

the output is 14
```

This is what is already written for me:

```
tile_dict = { 'A': 1, 'B': 3, 'C': 3, 'D': 2, 'E': 1, 'F': 4, 'G': 2, 'H': 4, 'I': 1, 'J': 8, 
          'K': 5, 'L': 1, 'M': 3, 'N': 1, 'O': 1, 'P': 3, 'Q': 10, 'R': 1, 'S': 1, 'T': 1, 
          'U': 1, 'V': 4, 'W': 4, 'X': 8, 'Y': 4, 'Z': 10 }
```

So now, I just had to write a code that will output the score of any word that is input. I am not sure where to start...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enumerate the word char by char, then use this char as key to the `tile_dict` dictionary to obtain character value. You can sum these values with [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#sum) function:

```py
word = "PYTHON"

cnt = sum(tile_dict[char] for char in word)
print(cnt)
```

Prints:

```
14
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input is `PYTHON`,

the output is: `PYTHON is worth 14 points.`

```
tile_dict = { 'A': 1, 'B': 3, 'C': 3, 'D': 2, 'E': 1, 'F': 4, 'G': 2, 'H': 4, 'I': 1, 'J': 8, 
              'K': 5, 'L': 1, 'M': 3, 'N': 1, 'O': 1, 'P': 3, 'Q': 10, 'R': 1, 'S': 1, 'T': 1, 
              'U': 1, 'V': 4, 'W': 4, 'X': 8, 'Y': 4, 'Z': 10 }    

word = input()

cnt = sum(tile_dict[char] for char in word)
print(f'{word} is worth {cnt} points.')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def isPalindrome(S):
  if S[0] == S[-1]
    return print("True")
  elif S[0] == S[-1] and S[1] == S[-2] :
    return print("True")
  else:
    return print("False")
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**